# É possivel desestruturar um objeto dentro de outro objeto?

Tags: javascript, objetos, declaração-de-variável

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu sei que é possível fazer isso com `arrays`, tipo um `array` assim

```
const array = [[['teste']]]
const [[[variavel]]] = array
variavel // => 'teste'
```

- existe alguma forma de fazer algo parecido com objetos?
- sem declarar a chave deles?

  const {teste1:{teste2:{teste3}}} = obj
  teste3 // => 'oi'

só que no caso assim `{{{teste3}}}`?

Comment: esse objeto está no formato inválido, pois todo objeto tem a característica de chave e valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por característica todo objeto em [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tem `chave` e `valor` e no exemplo precitado na sua pergunta o formato é inválido.

O formato válido é:

```
const c = {teste1:{teste2:{teste3:1}}}
```

e sua desestruturação:

```
const {teste1:{teste2:{teste3}}} = c;
console.log(teste3);
```

e assim funciona perfeitamente.

Exemplo funcional:

```js
const c = {teste1:{teste2:{teste3:1}}}
const {teste1:{teste2:{teste3}}} = c;
console.log(teste3);
```

Comment: entendi, obrigado pela resposta rapida, achei que era possivel igual a um array sem declarar essas chaves hehe, mais obrigado mesmo